# How to activate an instance of a ref class

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx, wrl

Say I have this class:

```
public ref class Page1 sealed : Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::Page {};
```

I can activate an instance of this class like this:

```
auto page = ref new Page1();
```

But how would I do that in raw C++?

I have tried this but it doesn't work:

```
Microsoft::WRL::Wrappers::HString className;
className.Set(L"App1.Page1");
IInspectable *page;
Windows::Foundation::ActivateInstance(className.Get(), &page);
```

The above code does work when I specify a windows runtime class name, (such as "Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Button"), just not my own ref class "App1.Page1".

---

Alternatively, given that I have declared a public ref class named `Page1` in the `App1` namespace, how can I activate an instance of this class as an `IInspectable*` from the HSTRING "App1.Page1"?

Comment: Getting a little pregnant with WRL doesn't generally work.  You'd normally declare the page in WRL as well and then you'll now the name since you have to declare it explicitly.  I *think* the C++/CX generated name is decorated with underscores to namespace_._classname, so would be "App1_._Page1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have figured it out. Well, this answer does not directly solve the problem of activating any arbitrary type, but it does what I want.

The devil is in the detail. The XAML compiler will generate a bunch of files not visible in the Solution Explorer. These files have the extension `.g.h` and `.g.hpp`. You can click the "Show All Files" button in Solution Explorer to see them.

In `App.g.h`, the App class implements the `Windows::UI::Xaml::Markup::IXamlMetadataProvider` class, which we can use to obtain information about our XAML types. The `XamlTypeInfo` files contains the generated type definitions.

Here's some code which shows how to activate one of our XAML types from a `TypeName`:

```
Object^ activate(TypeName typeName)
{
    auto app = Application::Current;
    auto provider = static_cast<IXamlMetadataProvider^>(app);
    auto xamlType = provider->GetXamlType(typeName);
    return xamlType->ActivateInstance();
}
```

No WRL necessary, 100% C++/CX, thanks to the XAML type information generated by the XAML compiler!

I believe a similar structure is also the case for C# projects, in that the `Application`-derived class will implement `IXamlMetadataProvider` interface too. Under the hood, the Windows Runtime does not use .NET, so it does not have any kind of "real" reflection, so it relies on statically defined type definitions.